# Bluetooth not working on ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503QM-HQ019 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers

I have just bought ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503QM-HQ019. It comes with AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS and NVIDIA RTX 3060 6GB.

I have a big problem. I have an Bluetooth Headset and Bluetooth is just not working on my laptop.

I have switched on Bluetooth settings in Ubuntu, nothing happens and when I close settings the switch goes off.

Looks like Ubuntu cannot detect Bluetooth module.

More about system:

- I have Windows as first system and Bluetooth works here perfectly.
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
- Linux kernel is 5.13.13-051313-generic, installed via Ubuntu Mainline.
- Wifi works perfectly
- Card is MT7921

So, does anybody know the solution for this?

Also, NVIDIA driver isn't working well, so if the solution for BT issues is to move to a new distributive, be free to write the one that compatible with my hardware.

UPD:

```
> sudo lshw | grep blue -C 8
                 *-usb:2    
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Wireless_Device
                      vendor: MediaTek Inc.
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:4
                      version: 1.00
                      serial: 000000000
                      capabilities: usb-2.10 bluetooth
                      configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.13.13-051313-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2
                   logical name: usb2
                   version: 5.13
```

Comment: Did you try a more up to date distro like Ubuntu 22.04 or Manjaro Linux?
Latest kernel releases have included some patches to this Asus laptops. I highly recommend trying Manjaro because It provides the latest kernels and NVidia drivers. Also check the asusctl utility:https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl .